# Wordpress post loop in page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom page template where I also want to display a list of posts.

Normally in a page you can just use the following code to display content

```
<?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

But what if before I display the page content, I have a custom query to display a list of posts? How can I after displaying those posts, go back to the original query to display page information?

Comment: That's explained in codex. with examples. since ages. https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your custom query, call wp_reset_postdata() function to get back default wordpress loop.

```
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

For more info and example check at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked that section in the documentation.